# What class is `ComponentRenderer` in Vaadin Sampler?

Tags: java, datagrid, vaadin

In [this demo Sampler of the `Grid` widget](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/component-renderer), the source code tab shows code calling a class named `ComponentRenderer`.

```
Map<CountryData, Double> countryRatings = new HashMap<>();
Grid<CountryData> countryGrid = new Grid<CountryData>(
        "Rate your favorite Countries");
countryGrid.setItems(countries);

countryGrid.addColumn(country -> new Label(country.getFullName()),
        new ComponentRenderer()).setCaption("Name");
countryGrid.addColumn(country -> {
    RatingStars ratingStars = new RatingStars();
    ratingStars.setMaxValue(5);
    ratingStars.setValue(countryRatings.containsKey(country)
            ? countryRatings.get(country) : 0.0d);
    ratingStars.addValueChangeListener(
            event -> countryRatings.put(country, event.getValue()));
    return ratingStars;
}, new ComponentRenderer()).setCaption("Rating");
```

I cannot find this class listed in the [Vaadin 8.0.3 API JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/api/). So what class is being used in this demo code?

Comment: Might it be this? https://github.com/datenhahn/componentrenderer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature coming up soon(ish) in Vaadin 8.1. Currently you can use it if you check out the alpha release from https://vaadin.com/releases

Comment: Update: Vaadin 8.1 is now released, including the `ComponentRenderer`.